# Lightroom mass undo last develop step?

Tags: lightroom

Is there a way to do a mass undo in lightroom's develop module?  I'd prefer not to push arrow key and click on the last step for this many photos.

The story, for those interested in face-palming: so I had adjust a setting and went to copy and paste the settings to every image from that day.  I thought I had unchecked everything, then clicked on what I had wanted, but somehow crop was selected.  Everything was pasted and I closed Lightroom to make a backup.

I open it and all of my photos which I had cropped selectively had lost their crop.  Ctrl+Z did nothing, as it doesn't remember things from the last session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd prefer not to push arrow key and click on the last step for this many photos.

You can get software (e.g. [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) to do this for you - you simply perform a complete cycle of the required actions once, letting the software record it, and then instruct it to repeat that sequence X times.

Not a perfect solution, but maybe good enough?

Comment: Most definitely good enough!